# What is the best practice for aligning table content for text/number mix?

Tags: tables, data-tables, alignment

What is the best practice for **aligning table content for text/number mix?**

I know that for text/string content it should be aligned to the left and for numbers it should be aligned to the right of the column.

But **what if I have a unique identification number which is something like: H2345633?**

It is mostly numbers but it is not entirely number based. **So how should it be aligned?**

Comment: http://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/portfolio/2016/1/7/data-looks-better-naked-clear-off-the-table

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The proposed duplicate asks "how to align contents, specifically decimal values" whereas this question is specifically asking about alignment of values made up of both characters and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard guidelines for aligning number as far as I know.

If numbers are with decimal points. For e.g. if the application is for financial domain **align them to the right, because they are easy to compare and  read.**

If it is a combination of text and number as you have stated align them to the left.